# Why does the bitcoin mining code have the same if statement twice?

Tags: mining-technical-details, bitcoin-core-development

From the v0.9.3 miner.cpp source (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.9.3/src/miner.cpp#L598-L604):

```
if (GetTimeMillis() - nHPSTimerStart > 4000)
{
    static CCriticalSection cs;
    {
        LOCK(cs);
        if (GetTimeMillis() - nHPSTimerStart > 4000)
        {
        ....
```

Why is the same if statement "`if (GetTimeMillis() - nHPSTimerStart > 4000)`" executed twice? GetTimeMillis() can only go up, so it seems like if the first one is true, then the second statement can only ever evaluate to true as well, and is useless. I'm assuming this is not entirely correct, though, and am also assuming it has something to do with the `CCriticalSelection`, but would like to understand the nature of it better.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree, I think that's a copy-paste bug. Maybe you should ask `#bitcoin-dev` to double-check.

Comment: Can any other thread modify `nHPSTimerStart`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. There could be quite a few threads working on the mining.

Comment: I have used something similar before. The first `if` checks if we should bother to do the potentially expensive lock. If yes, then we lock and now that `nHPSTimerStart` is guaranteed not to change we can safely execute the `if` again.

Comment: Thanks, Floris, that seems reasonable. If you post as an answer, I could mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which is

> ...a software design pattern used to reduce the overhead of acquiring a lock by first testing the locking criterion [...] without actually acquiring the lock.

This pattern can be fraught with issues; even folks who otherwise know what they're doing can be bitten by subtle issues.  See, for example, [C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) by Scott Meyers and Andrei Alexandrescu.

The particular use case you cite looks fairly innocuous, though.